# Excel VBA - Regex.Escape Method

Tags: regex, vba, excel

I was looking for a VBA code that can escape the special characters in regular expressions.  VB has a [Regex.Escape](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.escape%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) method.  Is there an equivalent in VBA?

Or is there a VBA code out there so I don't have to reinvent the wheel?  Thank you very much!

Edit: I meant the "Microsoft VBScript Regular Expression 5.5" library doesn't have a Regex.Escape method.  Is there an equivalent code out there?

[image]

Comment: VBA doesn’t have a native regexp - do you mean vbscript?

Comment: Read the docs - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/scripting-articles/ms974570(v=msdn.10)

Comment: @ Tim, unless I'm missing something, but the doc you were referring to only has `Test`, `Replace` and `Execute` methods.  It doesn't seem to have a `Escape` method (or something similar).  Can you please point me to the right direction?  Thank you!

Comment: Can you provide an example of the problem that you are having?

Comment: I have a VBA function that check the strings against regular expressions.  However, in some cases, I just want to compare with the pattern literally (i.e. treats "." as a dot, not a wildcard).  Of course I can build another function to put backslash (\) in front of the special characters.  But I don't want to reinvent the wheel if there's already something out there like [link]https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/character-escapes-in-regular-expressions

Comment: erm.. are you saying \ doesn't work in regex expression with vba?

Comment: Hi,  worth giving more detail in the question as to expected result along with some data. Here's your link as I've deleted my answer but remember to [edit] this info into your question. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.escape%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: \ does work.  But I have more to escape.  I just want to build something like Refex.Escape method.

Comment: Apologies I was a little flippant in my comment about reading the docs - should not post from my phone...  It does seem like you'd need to write your own method for this.

Answer (score 4):

You may use the following code:

```
Dim regExEscape As New RegExp
With regExEscape
    .pattern = "[-/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]"
    .Global = True
    .MultiLine = False
End With
```

Whenever you need to escape special characters in a user-defined string, use

```
.pattern = regExEscape.Replace(user_string, "\$&")
```

The `[-/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]` pattern contains a single character class that matches all possible metacharacters that you need to escape in a pattern to be treated as a literal character.  It matches `-`, `/`, `\`, `^`, `$`, `*`, `+`, `?`, `.`, `(`, `)`, `|`, `[`, `]`, `{`, `}`, and when you replace it with `\$&`, an escaping `\` is added right before them (the `$&` is a backreference to the whole match value).

Comment: Although I am not sure how, this worked for me. I was using a result from a previous regex.execute to build a new pattern, and that result contained metacharacters. This accurately escaped them. Thank you!